# Transformation Matrix of a function

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transformation

I have the following:

(Note: $V^{*}$ is defined as: $V^{*} = \{ L: V \rightarrow \mathbb{R} | \text{L is linear} \}$)

Let $V$ be an $\mathbb{R}$-Vectorspace. Let $\phi \in V^{*} \text{ \ } \{0 \}$ and $h \in V\text{ \ } \{0 \}$ with $h \in \ker{\phi}$. Let now $F: V \rightarrow V$ be given as $F(v) := v + \phi(v)  h$, where $B = (h, v_2, v_3 ... v_n)$ is a basis of $V$ with its first basis-vector $h$. Calculate the Transformation-Matrix $M_B(F)$.

Well, what I did was the trivial. I've applied $F(b_j) =  \sum_{i = 1}^n \lambda_i e_i$ with $b_j \in B$ and $j = 1,2,3 ... $

I will present the first two; $F(b_1)$ and $F(b_2)$. Note that $h\in ker(\phi) \Rightarrow \phi(h) = 0$:

$$f(h) = h + \phi(h)h = h = \lambda_1 e_1 + \lambda_2 e_2 + .. + \lambda_n e_n$$

$$f(v_2) = v_2 + \phi(v_2)h = \lambda_1 e_1 + \lambda_2 e_2 + .. + \lambda_n e_n$$

So what do I do next? I don't know how I can calculate the $\lambda$'s to be able to put them as entries into the matrix...

---

What if I said $h = \left(h_1, h_2, h_3, .... ,h_n \right)$ and defined every other vector $v_i = (v_{i,1}, v_{i,2}, ... ,v_{i,n})$.

Then I could write for $h$, that $h = h_1e_1 + h_2e_2 + h_3e_3 ... h_n e_n$ and for $v_2 + \phi(v_2)h = v_{2,1} + \phi(v_{2,1})h_1 e_1 + v_{2,n} + \phi(v_{2,2})h_2 e_2 + ... + v_{2,n} + \phi(v_{2,n})h_n e_n $...

Is that possible?

---

Thank you very much for your help.

FunkyPeanut

Comment: What does "$\,V\{0\}\;$" mean? Did you mean, by any chance, $\;V\setminus\{0\}\;$ ?

Comment: Yes, I did. sorry I oversaw that.

Comment: If nothing's said about the $\;v_2,v_3,...\;$ it  can be hard to know. Yet, as $\;0\neq \phi\in V^*\;$ , we know its kernel is a maximal non-trivial subspace of $\;V\;$ , meaning $\;\dim\ker\phi=n-1\;$, and we can choose a basis for $\;V\;$ with elements here...What were you given? Also, I think your $\;e_i$'s *have* to be the $\;v_i$'s ...

Comment: What are $e_1,e_2,\dots$? Is the question asking about a matrix relative to some other basis of $V$? It seems more natural to compute its matrix relative to $\{h,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$.

Comment: @DonAntonio Hmm... but what would that knowledge about the kernel help us? I have translated the task from German to English but I paid attention to not leave any information unspoken. That is really everything I have except for other subtasks I have not copied such as "calculate the Eigenvalues of $\det(M_B(F))$".

Comment: If you *can* choose the basis $\;B\;$ as to have $\;n-1\;$ elements from the kernel of $\;\phi\;$ then we're done. Otherwise, I can't see what can that lonely $\;h\in\ker\phi\;$ help us to get the matrix representation of $\;F\;$ ...other than $$F(h)=h=1\cdot h+0\cdot v_2+\ldots+0\cdot v_n$$and thus the matrix's first column is a $\;1\;$ and all the rest zeros...

Comment: @DonAntonio Ohh I see.... that means that it was wrong to use the canonical basis for that. As Greg Martin stated it is more natural to use B. Makes more sense and I'd agree to your latter statement.